# java8 stream map reduce cause a the ConcurrentModificationException, why?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, concurrentmodification

```
final BigDecimal couponlessAmount = orderItems.stream()
            .filter(item -> !item.getIsUseCoupon())
            .map(item -> item.getTotalAmount().subtract(item.getReduceProductAmount()))
            .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add);
```

something causes the `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1380) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:474) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
    at com.yijiupi.himalaya.ordercompute.provider.domain.component.computer.CouponUseLimitComputer.getMaxUseAmount(CouponUseLimitComputer.java:103) ~[classes/:?]
```

Comment: sometimes, not everytime, I think it's a bug of JDK, maybe JIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely to be JDK/JIT bug. As usually with `ConcurrentModificationException` it's a sign that your `orderItems` is concurrently modified from another thread. You should not use `ArrayList` concurrently without providing proper external synchronization. Note that wrapping `ArrayList` into `Collections.synchronizedList` is not enough here as it does not synchronizes traversals. As an alternative (if modifications are rare) use [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html).